# List *.h and *.cpp using bash

Tags: bash, glob, ls

I am using `bash` version 4.2.28 on Fedora 16. I have the `extglob` option set. I am trying to list all files matching `*.h` or `*.cpp` using `ls *(h|cpp)` but the command returns the following:

```
[agnel@damien cadcore]$ ls *(h|cpp)
ls: cannot access *(h|cpp): No such file or directory
```

I have verified that there are indeed several `.h` and `.cpp` files in my current directory. Am I doing something wrong or could this be a bug in `bash` or `ls`?

**Update:** Thank you for your answers. Using `*.h *.cpp` does what I need. However, I would still like to know why `extglob` didn't work like I expected.

Comment: Do you mean, "using `ls *.(h|cpp)`"?  (Maybe you don't, only the construct *looks* odd without the dot.)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ls (*h|*cpp)`?

Comment: You are simply misusing the extended glob notation. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extended glob `*(pattern-list)` matches 0 or more occurrences of the following pattern list. It does not match an arbitrary string followed by something from the option list. You want:

```
$ ls *.@(h|cpp)
```

This matches something, followed by a period, followed by either "h" or "cpp"

Comment: This is correct. I tried this ls *.@(h|c) in a directory with no .h and a few c files, and got this test1.c  test.c

Comment: Excellent, but how would you escape it, if you want to do this in a Makefile instead?

Comment: You would have to configure `make` to use `bash` (with the `extglob` option enabled) instead of `sh`. You would probably be better off just using two patterns `*.h *.cpp` instead.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need complicated globbing in this case: simply try `echo *.h *.cpp`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do just `ls *h *cpp`